# Bootstrap editable today's date not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, calendar

http://jsfiddle.net/pabin2/xBB5x/7872/

When i clicked on today button it should highlight the current date . But its not working for me. It brings to current month but current date is not highlighted . Please i need help to resolved this issue

```
[JS code][1]
```

Comment: please update proper fiddle url

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pabin2/xBB5x/7872/

Comment: Its highlighting current date only.

Comment: Damn — the editing system is weird.  Apparently, to include a JS Fiddle URL, the question must include code, but someone else was able to include just a URL.  Please can someone work out what the fix is — I'm out of my normal territory here.  Thanks; and sorry!

Comment: go to any other date for eg jan 3rd,2016 then click on today button , it moves to current month but date is not highlighted

Comment: @stanze did you found out my problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was , i used todayBtn: 'true' but inorder to highlight current date we need to use todayBtn: 'linked' .

[Reference](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#todayhighlight)